# How can I fix a Ikea Kallax shelf door

Tags: doors, shelving

I have an Ikea [Kallax](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/kallax-shelf-unit-white-10409932/) bookshelf which has these [insert doors](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/kallax-insert-with-door-white-20278167/). I bumped the door and ripped it off.

[image]

What would be a good way to fix it?

[image]

It looks like this happened before

From the other side

[image]

Is there some kind of putty I should try to stuff in the holes. Basically once busted out the cheap Ikea particle board is stripped and the screws have nothing to grab on. Should I take the door off and then use glue with some kind of clamp until it dries? Is the some other solution I should consider?

Comment: Can you add in a picture of the inside of the door showing the hinge? Does the panel with the screws sticking through it go all the way to the back of the cabinet? If so, I'd think you would be able to apply glue to the whole side of the panel to hold the thing in place. Then stop running into it because you'll probably destroy the hinge instead of pulling it out of the wood.

Answer (score 1):

I would first remove the door from its support panel.

Then screw and glue the panel to the side, locating it correctly and clamp it into place. Either use G-clamps or even make some wedges.

Once properly dry refit the door.